# How to run a ts script installed in node_modules with ts-node

Tags: typescript, node-modules, es6-modules, ts-node

I have a package containing a `script.ts` file:

```
import path from 'path'
/* ... */
const loaded = require(path.resolve(process.cwd(), './src/dynamicPath/example.ts'))
```

```json
// package.json
{
    "name": "mypackage",
    "bin": {
        "script": "./script.ts"
    }
}
```

It loads typescript files from the repo it's installed into. So I can't compile is and use node, I need to use `ts-node`

If I run `ts-node script.ts`, it **works fine**.

But when it's installed in `./node-modules/.bin/script.ts`.
If I run `ts-node ./node-modules/.bin/scripts` it doesn't work:

```
(node:25931) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
xxx/node_modules/.bin/script.ts:1
import path from 'path'
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
    ...
```

If I add `type: module` in `mypackage`'s `package.json` then I have this error:

```
TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for /__/node_modules/mypackage/script.ts
    at Loader.defaultGetFormat [as _getFormat] (internal/modules/esm/get_format.js:65:15)
    at Loader.getFormat (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:116:42)
    at Loader.getModuleJob (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:247:31)
    at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:181:17)
    at async Object.loadESM (internal/process/esm_loader.js:68:5) {
  code: 'ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION'
}
```

How can I make the typescript script from `node_modules` works the same as the ones outside `node_modules` ?

A `tsconfig.json` of a repo where I install `mypackage`:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "target": "es6",
        "lib": ["es2017"],
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "outDir": "dist",
        "types": ["node"],
        "sourceMap": true
    },
    "include": ["src/**/*", "./node_modules/.bin/script", "./node_modules/mypackage/**"]
}
```

I'm trying to avoid using a `postinstall` npm script to copy the file in my sources.

Comment: I tried running your script in the top-level folder various of my projects (effectively inheriting the tsconfig.json from each). I found in my nextjs and react projects where module was "esnext" I encountered the same error you reported. In my backend projects where module was "commonjs" I had no problem. So I think this is to do with how your environment expects modules to be composed in the different places.

Comment: Isn't it more conventional for everything in node_modules to be transpiled javascript not typescript, though. I'd expect something showing up as a bin in node_modules to have got there through an npm build script to turn typescript into the right kind of javascript module. There may be a strong assumption about this embedded in the behaviour you see.

Comment: No this is a typescript script it's not built because it imports other typescript files. It's in node_modules to be shared across multiple projects. I just want it to act like if it was at the top-level. I'll edit my answer to put my `tsconfig`

Comment: You can build typescript scripts that import other typescript files. That's a pretty fundamental aspect of typescript. Perhaps you mean that it can't be built because you want to be able to dynamically edit the typescript files it imports without running a build step each time? Understanding some of your motivation for not building a module but still putting it in node_modules would help responders.

Comment: No this is a typescript script not a js script I can't build it, it imports local typescript files dynamically from the top-level sources and I want to update it easily in `node_modules`. I just want to ship that script in different repo and use `ts-node` but apparently `ts-node` can't run scripts from `node_modules`. Also the script is already written I'm not going to refactor it.

Comment: I think I understand. So you already have a way for another repo to 'send' files into all your projects. You want to use this mechanism to to run a script that references (imports) ts files in the project itself, so it's a dependency that sort of depends on its importing package, and then performs some steps. All the importing packages have enough in common that a single script can consistently import them. But the mechanism you've chosen for shipping the script ends up breaking the script. Is that right?

Comment: @cefn yes. I think it's just not possible to use `ts-node` like that so I'll probably end up with a postinstall to move the script to the top-level...

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that you have `"esModuleInterop": true` in both **tsconfigs** - in **mypackage** and in **dependent project** where you are installing **mypackage** into.
2. add `#!ts-node` on top of **script.ts** file
3. no need to do `ts-node ./node-modules/.bin/script` do `npx script` instead (in directory of **dependent project** where you are installing **mypackage**)